# How to delete Python files via explorer

Tags: windows, python-3.x, windows-10

I want to delete some old python files via file explorer (Windows 10)  but I cannot find the files, except in the quick-access folder. There is no way to delete files in the quick-access folder. Can you help me? I'm looking for a folder 
which includes all my python files. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you right click on the folder itself, you should see something like "Go to directory" or "Go to file location" or anything similar to that. Once you go there, delete the folder.